# Linking to my own blog

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In my most recent reply I linked to my own blog, as it provided a many hundred word expansion on area of the [question](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/what-is-a-good-mastering-chain-to-use-in-a-daw) I was answering on audio.stackexchange.com.

The linked blog post was not written for the sake of the answer here (it was composed many months ago), nor does it contain any enticement to buy any services, specific recommendations of any gear, or anything that I feel constitutes self-promotion. It is merely a useful exposition on the topic.

Still I wanted to ask if this was appropriate behavior. A link to the post in question is [here](http://www.passbandllc.com/2011/02/mid-side/) so the moderators can decide for themselves. I am trying to be a good citizen.

Comment: Both the questioin and the blog now appear to be dead links.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for bringing it up- I appreciate having the discussion out in the open.

I personally don't see anything wrong with it. You clearly marked the link as your own blog, and described it as a "primer" so it's clearly only there as an aside to the question, for those who aren't familiar with mid/side processing.

If it looked like it was a ploy to drive blog traffic I'd have an issue with it, but as it is it just looks informational and helpful, which is exactly the goal.

Comment: I'm of course interested in hearing what everyone else has to say about it, but these are my thoughts upon seeing the question.

Comment: 100% agreed. The blog post contained information that was relevant to my question. I can't see any problem with this at all.

Comment: I agree, looks fine to me.

Comment: Agreed, I have no problem with this. Have done it myself.